# How to go from a List with 17 elements to more elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Phyton. I have this list:

```
[
    '0 214.0 1.55E-02 233.6',
    '10 205.0 6.470E-03 228.5',
    '20 188.3 2.630E-03 218.8',
    '30 175.0 9.800E-04 211.0',
    '40 162.4 3.400E-04 203.6',
    '50 152.2 1.080E-04 197.0',
    '60 144.2 3.180E-05 191.6',
    '70 139.5 8.730E-06 188.4',
    '80 139.0 2.290E-06 187.9',
    '90 139.0 6.010E-07 188.2',
    '100 139.0 1.590E-07 188.1',
    '110 149.4 4.140E-08 195.5',
    '120 159.7 1.190E-08 202.5',
    '130 170.0 3.760E-09 208.6',
    '140 245.1 1.090E-09 251.9',
    '150 288.6 4.730E-10 275.5'
]
```

with 17 elements. Every element has 4 'subelements' and I would like to have a list with 17X4 elements.

i.e., every number (0, 214.0, 1.55E-02, 233.6) should be an element of my list.

How can I do that?

Comment: Anything you've tried yourself? Also put the list in the code tags.

Comment: I was trying to simply replace the spacing between numbers with a comma, as to indicate a new element. Or to split elements in my list, but id didn t work. Sorry but I m really new to programming and don t really know where to start to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the numbers are **separated by spaces**. Turning a string into string according to a certain split string is what **`str.split(..)`** is doing.

So you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)[1]:

```
[list(x.split()) for x in mylist]
```

Which gives:

```
>>> [list(x.split()) for x in mylist]
[['0', '214.0', '1.55E-02', '233.6'], ['10', '205.0', '6.470E-03', '228.5'], ['20', '188.3', '2.630E-03', '218.8'], ['30', '175.0', '9.800E-04', '211.0'], ['40', '162.4', '3.400E-04', '203.6'], ['50', '152.2', '1.080E-04', '197.0'], ['60', '144.2', '3.180E-05', '191.6'], ['70', '139.5', '8.730E-06', '188.4'], ['80', '139.0', '2.290E-06', '187.9'], ['90', '139.0', '6.010E-07', '188.2'], ['100', '139.0', '1.590E-07', '188.1'], ['110', '149.4', '4.140E-08', '195.5'], ['120', '159.7', '1.190E-08', '202.5'], ['130', '170.0', '3.760E-09', '208.6'], ['140', '245.1', '1.090E-09', '251.9'], ['150', '288.6', '4.730E-10', '275.5']]
```

Note that the elements here are **`str`ings**, if you want `float`s, you can write:

```
[[float(y) for y in x.split()] for x in mylist]
```

which gives:

```
>>> [[float(y) for y in x.split()] for x in mylist]
[[0.0, 214.0, 0.0155, 233.6], [10.0, 205.0, 0.00647, 228.5], [20.0, 188.3, 0.00263, 218.8], [30.0, 175.0, 0.00098, 211.0], [40.0, 162.4, 0.00034, 203.6], [50.0, 152.2, 0.000108, 197.0], [60.0, 144.2, 3.18e-05, 191.6], [70.0, 139.5, 8.73e-06, 188.4], [80.0, 139.0, 2.29e-06, 187.9], [90.0, 139.0, 6.01e-07, 188.2], [100.0, 139.0, 1.59e-07, 188.1], [110.0, 149.4, 4.14e-08, 195.5], [120.0, 159.7, 1.19e-08, 202.5], [130.0, 170.0, 3.76e-09, 208.6], [140.0, 245.1, 1.09e-09, 251.9], [150.0, 288.6, 4.73e-10, 275.5]]
```

Note that these are **lists of lists of floats**. In case you want a **flat list**, you can use:

```
[float(y) for x in mylist for y in x.split()]
```

which generates:

```
>>> [float(y) for x in mylist for y in x.split()]
[0.0, 214.0, 0.0155, 233.6, 10.0, 205.0, 0.00647, 228.5, 20.0, 188.3, 0.00263, 218.8, 30.0, 175.0, 0.00098, 211.0, 40.0, 162.4, 0.00034, 203.6, 50.0, 152.2, 0.000108, 197.0, 60.0, 144.2, 3.18e-05, 191.6, 70.0, 139.5, 8.73e-06, 188.4, 80.0, 139.0, 2.29e-06, 187.9, 90.0, 139.0, 6.01e-07, 188.2, 100.0, 139.0, 1.59e-07, 188.1, 110.0, 149.4, 4.14e-08, 195.5, 120.0, 159.7, 1.19e-08, 202.5, 130.0, 170.0, 3.76e-09, 208.6, 140.0, 245.1, 1.09e-09, 251.9, 150.0, 288.6, 4.73e-10, 275.5]
```

If you want to do *matrix* or *vector* calculations in bulk, then usually one uses a library like `numpy`. You can import your data in numpy as follows:

```
import numpy as np

np.fromstring(' '.join(mylist),sep=' ')
```

producing:

```
>>> np.fromstring(' '.join(mylist),sep=' ')
array([  0.00000000e+00,   2.14000000e+02,   1.55000000e-02,
         2.33600000e+02,   1.00000000e+01,   2.05000000e+02,
         6.47000000e-03,   2.28500000e+02,   2.00000000e+01,
         1.88300000e+02,   2.63000000e-03,   2.18800000e+02,
         3.00000000e+01,   1.75000000e+02,   9.80000000e-04,
         2.11000000e+02,   4.00000000e+01,   1.62400000e+02,
         3.40000000e-04,   2.03600000e+02,   5.00000000e+01,
         1.52200000e+02,   1.08000000e-04,   1.97000000e+02,
         6.00000000e+01,   1.44200000e+02,   3.18000000e-05,
         1.91600000e+02,   7.00000000e+01,   1.39500000e+02,
         8.73000000e-06,   1.88400000e+02,   8.00000000e+01,
         1.39000000e+02,   2.29000000e-06,   1.87900000e+02,
         9.00000000e+01,   1.39000000e+02,   6.01000000e-07,
         1.88200000e+02,   1.00000000e+02,   1.39000000e+02,
         1.59000000e-07,   1.88100000e+02,   1.10000000e+02,
         1.49400000e+02,   4.14000000e-08,   1.95500000e+02,
         1.20000000e+02,   1.59700000e+02,   1.19000000e-08,
         2.02500000e+02,   1.30000000e+02,   1.70000000e+02,
         3.76000000e-09,   2.08600000e+02,   1.40000000e+02,
         2.45100000e+02,   1.09000000e-09,   2.51900000e+02,
         1.50000000e+02,   2.88600000e+02,   4.73000000e-10,
         2.75500000e+02])
```

[1] [*Python 2 Tutorial's section on "list comprehensions"*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: I think the OP wanted a flat list?

Comment: Thank you very much . I really appreciate you took the time to answer

Comment: I guess it's the way you interpret it. Well, as long as the author is happy, I am happy.

Comment: Yes that s what I needed. Thanks everyone

Comment: @elena: I've updated the answer with a flat list (such that the OP and future readers can pick their favorite :)

Comment: A link to the [Python 2 Tutorial's section on "list comprehensions"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) might be appropriate, so that the OP and other Python beginners can look up what's going on here.

Comment: @das-g: that's a great idea. Updated.